# How can I call a function in javascript that contains a period in it's name?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following object:

```
var helloWorldFunctions = {
                           'hello.world': function () { return 'hello world'},
                           'helloWorld' : function () { return 'hello world'}
                          }
```

I can call the second 'helloWorld' function in the object by doing:

```
helloWorldFunctions.helloWorld()
```

How can I call the first 'hello.world' function? Naturally, doing the following gives me a type error:

```
helloWorldFunctions.hello.world()
```

Comment: The function has no "name". Rather the expression `hellowWorldFunctions["hello.world"]` (note it's just a normal key lookup) will return a function-object that can be called. This access (with the brackets, supplying a string as a key) is no different than accessing any other value in an object.

Comment: `helloWorldFunctions['hello.world']()` You can use bracket notation.

Comment: you can do `helloWorldFunctions['hello.world']()` but why would you even have a period in the name?

Comment: @user2864740: It does as of ES2015, try this in a recent version of Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/xc9a74cs/ (Firefox *still* doesn't properly support the `name` property on functions).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Very nifty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rajaprabhu suggested in the comments, you can use:

```
helloWorldFunctions['hello.world']()
```